# assingning scrollbars to a layout which is has two child layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

The XML file for my activity has `ScrollView` as rootview . it has two relative layout as child . this is giving me error .

I want to keep two relative layout as child view in `ScrollView` of this XML.

Here is my XML file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_about">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAboutUs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="clip_vertical"
            android:text="@string/about_us"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_weight="0.96"
        android:background="#E8E9EA" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I want it to be scroll-able either the whole layout or just the second layout.

Comment: the layout you have provided is written completely wrong. it has many missing parameters. why dont you tell me what you need , what would be your layout like. and i will help you make it.

Comment: You can't have more than 1 child per ScrollView - it can have many grand-children but only one child. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap one of your layouts in a `ScrollView` (or `HorizontalScrollView`, if you want it that way) or if you want the `ScrollView` at the root, place it at the start of your code. Either way, you have to ensure that there is only ONE child element for the `ScrollView` (this child element can have many child elements) - below is an example of the whole thing being scrollable:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_about">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAboutUs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="clip_vertical"
                android:text="@string/about_us"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </RelativeLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>         
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I'll try to see if it matches my requirement. thank you.

Comment: @sharadchauhan it's because ScrollViews cannot have more than 1 child. Wrap your children in another layout, such as a LinearLayout and your problem will be solved. Please see my edit